# Isn't losing reputation for down voting encouraging people to post wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I've discovered that if you down vote a answer then you lose reputation. I don't understand why this happens as it just discourages me from down voting answers that are completely wrong. Because of this you just end up getting completely random answers at the top of a question page that users don't want to down vote because they then lose reputation.

I can understand this may be because users can start having down vote wars and that but I'm sure Stack Overflow could simply implement a feature where you can have a down vote reviewed if you think it's wrong.

Comment: If enough people downvote the answer will be deleted and you will get your rep back ;)

Comment: Yes, but if enough people don't down vote then you basically lose your reputation for trying to help the community.

Comment: Once you have more rep the little loss will not matter. Until then: Trust others are there.. Also: Leaving a comment pointing out the problem has a godd chance to clear things up, maybe better than an anonymous downvote..

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of us with effectively infinite reputation available to downvote. If you believe that reputation is correlated with having a clue (and not everyone does), then having *us* do the downvoting as opposed to people who have not shown evidence of cluefullness is a good thing.

Comment: Then it might as well be you can't down vote anything until your over a certain reputation.

Comment: @Hydra you can't down vote anything until you're over [125 reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) (note if you have 125 and vote down one answer, and that drops you to 124, you can't vote down anymore)

Answer (score 3):

You really need to justify, if an answer doesn't apply well for a question. There's this barrier to prevent to disprove such answers by mere misunderstanding, or following previous downvotes.

Opening this Pandora box, might lead to much worse behaviour overall.

Even if a question is off-topic, serious answering attempts are still valid, and shouldn't be downvoted, unless consciously loosing rep doing so.

Comment: "might lead to much worse behavior overall". Surely there can be a feature added to allow answerers to report a down vote or request a block if a user is trying to have a down vote war.