# Why was this answer down-voted?

Tags: support, downvotes, specific-answer

[Down-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219776/scanning-a-txt-file-and-creating-an-array-out-of-strings-in-this-case-vending/33219949#33219949)

It's a genuine answer from a newbie trying to help. Surely that shouldn't get a minus score? How else will ai learn?

Comment: Because [Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397).

Comment: Nobody can tell *why* or *who* downvoted something. You'll however notice that *each* answer on that question was. So it's possible that someone took offense at the question already (which really isn't that great), and votes on the answers are just collateral damage.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: If you take offence to a question isn't the appropriate response to down-vote the question? I'm not sure if I fully understand why someone would attack everyone involved even if they're not directly implicated in the supposed original crime.

Comment: If you remove links from your answer it reads as *"It looks to me like you just want to create an array of strings. However, depending on what you're trying to do exactly (I couldn't make out from the question), you may wish to consider using key value pairs."*, which is not a great answer. I'd post it as comment.

Comment: It's not amazing coz I'm new and learning. But it's a valid and fair reading of the question. I haven't been coding 30 years and I don't get paid to but I am try to help. Shouldn't negative rep be for people who do something that harms the community?

Comment: But I take your point about comments. I shouldn't have been chasing the teacher badge for the sake of it :).

Comment: One thing Peter : If you don't get valid feedback about what you have as good and bad answers, how will you learn? You say you won't learn because you get downvoted. But if you DON'T get downvoted, you'll think it's all good and continue what you're doing

Comment: Also, Peter, before you come back and say the question got downvoted because you linked it, there is such a thing as the Meta Effect. Linking ANYTHING into meta means people who care a lot about site quality will see it and act on it. So if it's worthy of downvotes, it'll be downvoted even more. It's unfortunate, but it goes both ways (good linked questions usually get even MORE upvoted)

Comment: It's ironic how people were defending an answer that had a picture of Milla Jovovich with the words ***"it's technically an answer, just a poor one"*** and now this guy is getting all of SO's guidelines thrown at him over the fact that he posted links that would solve OP's problem saying that ***"this is not an answer"*** . Yes maybe it isn't an answer, yes maybe it should've been a comment. But you can't expect us to believe the fact that users prefer to defend a troll answer over an honest( and "poor" if you want to see it that way) attempt to help the community.

Comment: In dis place:

http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302572/isnt-losing-reputation-for-down-voting-encouraging-people-to-post-wrong-answers?rq=1

It says:

**Leaving a comment pointing out the problem has a godd chance to clear things up, maybe better than an anonymous downvote.. – TaW Sep 15 at 10:56**

Is dis not true?

Comment: peter, don't write in text speech... "this" please. While it's true this has a BETTER chance, no one is obligated to do it, and you shouldn't expect that people will

Comment: In this particular case it was considered that the sonic resonance of the psuedo-word 'dis' was preferable to the standard English word 'this' in conveying the desired emotive overtones. However, while the intended meaning seems to be conveyed to all parties, I can understand that you may have had an adverse personal reaction to my 'text speech'. In particular I wonder if you are given to interpret the evoked modes of childhood speech as reminiscent of immature speech patterns, rather than suggestive of an engaged care-giver moderating their vocalisations to aid child development.

Comment: Or, probably more accurately in this case, a coder looking to utilise biologically and culturally engineered patterns to evoke a nurturing, rather than corrective response, as befits the approach one might take to a human in the earlier stages of development as opposed to, say, a rebellious or antagonistic teenager.

Comment: And now you sound overly pedantic, and honestly snarky. Honestly, it's the fact that in general, we do ask people to check their grammar, and I've seen downvoted questions because of uncapitalized "i"s, text speech and the like, so you're not helping your case by writing thusly. If you want a real discussion, I'll be happy to have one with you. If you just want to switch to a snarky mode to what I say, I see no reason to continue this conversation

Comment: I was just explaining why I used the particular syntax in this case. No snarkiness intended. You told me not to use a particular style of phrasing and I defended my decision with reason and logic. My life's passion and university training has been in linguistics and related subjects and that was my route into coding. I was trying to explain the reasons why I made my linguistic choice and that they we 100% deliberate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it justifiable to downvote a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252677/when-is-it-justifiable-to-downvote-a-question)

Answer (score 28):

Your answer is merely stating that the question is a duplicate and linking to that duplicate.  If you think that the question is a duplicate then *flag the question for closure as a duplicate*, don't post an answer stating that it's a duplicate.

You also indicated that the question is unclear.  If you think a question is unclear you should be flagging/voting to close the question as unclear, and optionally commenting to try to help the author clarify their question.  You shouldn't be posting an answer when the question isn't clear.

> [...] a newbie trying to help. Surely that shouldn't get a minus score? How else will [I] learn

Answers are voted on based on their content, not based on how new or old the author is.  When you post a bad answer, you get a downvote, whether you're user12345 or Jon Skeet.  When you post a good answer, you get an upvote.  Getting feedback on the quality of your posts based on their content, rather than how long you've been with the site, is *exactly* how you learn.  You've been given valuable feedback on the fact that you posted a low quality answer.  Learn from that.  Had the person not downvoted you, you wouldn't have realized that you posted a bad answer, and wouldn't have learned anything.

Comment: I'm not sure how you could prove your case since Jon is repcapped every day.

Comment: @MartinJames Well at a minimum that's the goal.  If someone is saying that a post is being voted on based off of its content and not treated differently because of who the user is then *that's what we want*.  Of course, in practice, that doesn't *always* happen, but it is the goal we strive for.

Comment: *Answers are voted on based on their content* says the guy who was okay with having Milla Jovovich as an answer, **smh**

Comment: @xPeke I said that the answer merited being downvoted.  It was a bad answer.  I didn't say it was great and should be upvoted, or that I upvoted it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a link-only answer.  *Yes*, the links come back to the site, but there's not much substance in the answer alone.

Here's what it looks like without the hyperlinks:

> It looks to me like you just want to create an array of strings, in
>   which case your question is a duplicate of this one:
>
> However, depending on what you're trying to do exactly (I couldn't
>   make out from the question), you may wish to consider using key value
>   pairs, which is already covered here:

Without the links, where's the answer at?  What's the value being conveyed here?

Comment: @Pnuts then it's not an answer and should be the auto-comment from flagging as a dupe? I still don't think this is an ANSWER, no?

Comment: @pnuts Analyzing the content of an answer without any of its links is a useful tool for determining whether a post is actually posting an answer (rather than directing the user to an answer that is elsewhere).

Comment: @pnuts:  What's the spirit of the policy?  An answer should be able to hold its own without heavy reliance on external references.  This answer doesn't even come close to holding its own without those links.

Comment: @pnuts hmmm fair enough, yeah i can see this. I should've phrased my "not an answer" as "answer worthy of a downvote". But you're totally right, it IS an answer... just a bad one

Answer (score -4):

Don't worry about a single downvote.

But back to your specific case. Your answer was clearly helpful, but failed a few unobvious community rules.

- As mentioned already it's a link-only answer. Of course you can reference similar answers, but prefer to include an adaptation or an excerpt, or explain why it might fit a specific question.
- Typically we prefer to duplicate-close questions on similar topics. Of course new users aren't obliged to know that already, and it's hardly relevant until you have 3K points.
- And your question didn't only link to another answer, but two different topics. Which already makes it visually and technically exempt from the not-just-a-link-answer rule *in my opinion*.

  Moreover, while such answers don't often receive upvotes, they're helpful still to closevoters. (Someone might take one of your two links and close the question should it fit.)
- Personally I'm more lenient on new users - especially when posting answers. There's no reason new users should be upheld to *exactly* the same standards as high rep users.

  - You don't have to post extremely stellar answers to garner upvotes.
  - OTOH you can't expect to be exempt from downvotes for useless ones.
- Now this isn't one of those cases. As I mentioned earlier it was just another user downvoting the question and all the answers alongside. - Which is perfectly fine if that user thought the question is pointless and the answers attracted so far made it worse.
- And I'm just gonna say it: That you garnered `-8` on your answer after posting on meta was totally unwarranted. Yes, it wasn't a great answer with much content. But you just asked why it was badly received, and that's precisely what meta is for.

  Don't take it personally, it's just extra scrutinity and the "[meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect)". Don't refrain from asking here again.

Comment: _"and it's hardly relevant until you have 3K points."_ You only need 50 rep to _flag_ as duplicate, which gets the closure-ball rolling. Yes, the OP here couldn't have done _that_ either, but 50 rep is where you can start worrying about duplicates.

Comment: It might also have served better as comment, where link-only references make more sense IMO. The crux is of course that OP didn't yet have the necessary rep for either. -- And 3K also just opens up a privilege, not an obligation to closevote, of course.

Comment: @mario The fact that the OP doesn't have enough rep to comment doesn't make it acceptable to post comments as answers.

Comment: @Servy And that's not what OP did. At no point did he indicate that he orginally intended to post a comment. It's what his answer looks like. But that's not why it was voted on that way.

Comment: @mario The OP posted an answer to say that the question is unclear, but provides a link to two questions which might be duplicates, depending on how the question is interpreted.  That is not an appropriate course of action on SO.  If he felt the question was unclear, he should have flagged for closure as unclear.  If he thinks he's found a duplicate, or wants to ask the OP if a given question matches what he's asking, then that should be a comment (which, as I said previously, doesn't make it okay to post as an answer just because you don't have 50 rep).

Comment: @Servy Yep. Somebody should have told him that per ←comment on his answer. However that's a little late now, and presumably wasn't the reason for the original downvote which triggered this meta discussion.

Comment: So that excludes him from participating then? @Servy

Comment: @mario You have no idea whether or not that was the cause of the original downvote.  For all you know it was.

Comment: @xPeke I explained exactly how he could have participated in an appropriate manor, at the rep level that he has.  And the fact that some of the additional actions that would have been nice would require more rep than he was in no way excludes taking inappropriate actions.